# WebBrowser control - page rendering error after install IE 11

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, web, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I have problem with Winforms .NET Class "WebBrowser" **after installing** of Internet Explorer 11 Preview. It looks like disable javascipt when I call my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `WebBrowser`-based app and your web pages still work fine with IE10, the following is likely to be the reason for the problem.

In a rather controversial decision, [Microsoft has changed the traditional layout of IE User Agent (UA) string in IE11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx).

This is what the UI string looks like in IE11:

```
 navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
 document.documentMode: 11
 document.compatMode: CSS1Compat
```

This is what it used to look like in IE10 and older versions:

```
 navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0;)
 document.documentMode: 10
 document.compatMode: CSS1Compat
```

While a well-designed web page should not rely upon UA string to detect available HTML features, a lot of existing pages still do, and such change may have confused them.

If you have no control over the web pages you load, and cannot fix them, one way to restore the traditional UA string is to force IE7 emulation with [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) for your `WebBrowser`-based app. Unfortunately, you'd have to go for as low as IE7. Specifying a higher version does't restore the old UA string layout.

Another, more flexible but more complex way to fix this is to set up a custom UA string via `UrlMkSetSessionOption`/`URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT` WinAPI. You should retrieve the current UI string with `UrlMkGetSessionOption`, parse it, add the missing parts and set it back with `UrlMkSetSessionOption`. Do it in the `static` constructor of your `Form` class, before `WebBrowser` object gets instantiated.

**[UPDATE]** The code for changing the user agent string:

```
static public void ChangeUserAgentForIE11()
{
    if (GetIEVersion() <= 10)
        return;

    var userAgent = new StringBuilder(256);
    int length = 0;
    Win32.UrlMkGetSessionOption(Win32.URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, userAgent, userAgent.Capacity-1, ref length, 0);

    // IE10: navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)
    // IE11: navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko

    var regex = new Regex(@"^\s*(Mozilla/\d+\.\d+\s+\()(Windows\s+.*)like Gecko\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //IE11 regex
    var match = regex.Match(userAgent.ToString());
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var newUserAgent = String.Concat(match.Groups[1], "compatible; MSIE 10.0; ", match.Groups[2]);
        Win32.UrlMkSetSessionOption(Win32.URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, newUserAgent, newUserAgent.Length, 0);
        var verifyUserAgent = new StringBuilder(256);
        length = 0;
        Win32.UrlMkGetSessionOption(Win32.URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, verifyUserAgent, verifyUserAgent.Capacity-1, ref length, 0);
        if (verifyUserAgent.ToString() != newUserAgent)
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to change WebBrowser User Agent.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but hotfix not working. How can I easy set UrlMkSetSessionOption in .NET?

Comment: @majco333, not sure what you mean by "hotfix". I've posted the relevant code, leaving `GetIEVersion` and `Win32` p/invoke definitions for you to implement as an exercise.

Comment: What must I import to my .net project for Win32 functions? Because I didn't see in my project. Thanks

Comment: This works for me: 

<DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Function UrlMkSetSessionOption(ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal pBuffer As String, ByVal dwBufferLength As Integer, ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
End Function

I used this user agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36

Noseratio: thanks!!!