# Forcing Embedded IE 8 mode when IE9 or greater installed

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control

Based on [this helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome#comment600853_790542), I followed [these instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) to set IE Mode for a .NET process that's using the embedded IE web control. However, 8000 and 8888 values don't guarantee IE 8 mode.  They set the embedded browser to identify itself as the latest IE version installed on the system.  So, if I have IE 9 installed I can see the agent string in the http request as IE 9.  If 10 then 10.  Are there other values or settings to change to force IE 8 mode even if IE 9 or greater is installed?

Comment: Besides `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, you would also need to provide a custom user agent string to match that of IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19601064/1768303

Comment: Thanks Noseratio.  Unfortunately, the application isn't under my control, so I was looking for other means - like registry settings.  Your link lead me to [all registly settings for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx), but I didn't see anything applicable.

Comment: Alex, I don't think you can customize the UA string per-process through the registry.